# Unique character of order 2

Tags: group-theory, characters

"The multiplicative group $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$of reduced residue classes modulo an odd prime p is a cyclic group of (even) order p − 1. Thus it has
a **unique** character of order 2."

Why we only have one character of order 2? What has this to do with the first statement above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\chi:G\to\Bbb{C}^*$, $G$ a finite abelian group, is a character of order two, it follows that $1=\chi(g)^2=\chi(g^2)$ for all $g\in G$. This implies that

- the kernel of $\chi$ contains all the squares in $G$, and
- $\chi(g)=\pm1$ for all $g\in G$.

If we furthermore know that $G$ is cyclic of an even order $n=2m$, then

- the squares form a subgroup $Q\le G$ of order $m$ and index two, and therefore
- the coset $gQ=G\setminus Q$ for any non-square element $g$. Implying that the product of two non-squares is a square, and that the product of a square and a non-square is a non-square.

So if $\chi$ has order two, then

1. $\chi(q)=1$ for all $q\in Q$,
2. $\chi(x)\neq1$ for some $x\in G$. By the above observations $x\notin Q$, and $\chi(x)=-1$.
3. If $y\notin Q$, then $yQ=xQ$ implying that $y=xq$ for some square $q\in Q$.
4. So $\chi(y)=\chi(xq)=\chi(x)\chi(q)=(-1)\cdot1=-1$.
5. Items 1 and 4 imply that $\chi$ is the unique function taking the value $+1$ in $Q$, and the value $-1$ elsewhere.
6. It easily follows that the function defined in the previous bullet is actually a character of $G$.

---

As Hempelicious pointed out, the character group of an abelian group is isomorphic to the group itself. But, the isomorphism is not *natural*. In other words, it relies on our ability to write a finite abelian group as a direct product of cyclic groups. Such a decomposition is not unique, and this leads to complications similar to the well known result that the dual of a f.d. vector space is isomorphic to the vector space itself, but to write down the isomorphism you need to specify a basis. In sharp contrast to the simpler fact that the double dual is *naturally* isomorphic to the vector space we started with.

Comment: I guess another way of saying this is that in the abelian case, the character is actually a homomorphism. Since there is only one subgroup of order $2$ in $\mathbb{C}^\ast$, there's still most one such character.

Comment: @Hempelicious Cyclicity is also essential. If $G=C_2\times C_2$ then it has three characters of order two. The generators of the two factors can both be mapped to $\mapsto\pm1$. We get a character of order two unless we make the trivial selection. Similarly, that group has three subgroups of index two, and each can serve as the kernel of a character of order two.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I left that part out, but I meant once we know they're homomorphisms, they can be counted by the index 2 subgroups. This wouldn't be true if the image had more than one element of order 2.

Comment: Ok, @Hempelicious. We seem to agree :-)

Answer (score 1):

Characters of finite abelian groups are in 1-1 correspondence with the groups themselves. See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1694696/320311) for more details.

Comment: Honestly: Never heard of that fact. I mean with that my question is obviously answered but its not really obvious that your assumption is correct.

Comment: @FabianSchneider: not an assumption, it's proved at the link. Please read the answers there.